# HEX Protocol over TCP

Tags: php, hex

I need to send and receive over tcp hex messagges following this specs:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aBR5xCxB3DvTzoaYERwRDYS5NyBu_8mR

The communications is from/to a hlk-dio16 controller (hardware)

I'm trying with this source code in php

```
$address="192.168.1.161";
$port="8080";
$msg="aa 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 bb";
$msg = str_replace(" ", "", strtoupper($msg));

$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create a     socket");

socket_connect($sock,$address,$port) or die("Could not connect to the socket");
$ret = socket_write($sock,hex2bin($msg));
print($ret);

$read=socket_read($sock,1024);
echo " read :$read\n";
echo socket_last_error();

$ret = socket_write($sock,("0x".$msg));
print($ret);

$read=socket_read($sock,1024);

echo " read :$read\n";
echo socket_last_error();

socket_close($sock);
```

The socket is created correctly, and data seems sent.. but I receive 0 lenght data in $read variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `xx` at byte 18 in the datasheet needs to be filled in with something other than `00`, I found some other code written in python:

```py
    def format_packet(command):
        """Format packet to be sent."""
        frame_header = b"\xaa"
        verify = b"\x0b"
        send_delim = b"\xbb"
        return frame_header + command.ljust(17, b"\x00") + verify + send_delim
```

From: https://github.com/jameshilliard/hlk-sw16/blob/master/hlk_sw16/protocol.py#L138-L143

For embedded black-boxes one thing that really helps is finding a setup that works, even if its written in a different language than you prefer, and either read the code or sniff the packets being sent.